Nuxt 3 and tailwindCSS
Im learning nuxt 3 and taillwindcss
if i add bagroundImages as an extend in tailwind.config.js
first method

  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        darkBlue: "hsl(217, 28%, 15%)",
        darkBlue1: "hsl(218, 28%, 13%)",
        darkBlue2: "hsl(216, 53%, 9%)",
        darkBlue3: "hsl(219, 30%, 18%)",
        accentCyan: "hsl(176, 68%, 64%)",
        accentBlue: "hsl(198, 60%, 50%)",
        lightRed: "hsl(0, 100%, 63%)",   
    },
      backgroundImage: {
        'logo-dark-mode': "url('~/assets/images/logo-dark-mode.svg')",
        'logo-light-mode': "url('~/assets/images/logo-light-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-dark-mode': "url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-dark-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-light-mode': "url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-light-mode.svg')",
    },
  },

and if i do this nothing happend
<div class="bg-curvy-light-mode dark:curvy-dark-mode bg-no-repeat bg-contain bg-bottom">
    <div class="container mx-auto px-6 text-center md:pt-20 pb-52">
        <img src="~/assets/images/illustration-intro.png" class="mx-auto" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

but if i add the image url as Arbitrary values i can see the image
second method
<div class="bg-[url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-light-mode.svg')] dark:[url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-dark-mode.svg')] bg-no-repeat bg-contain bg-bottom">
    <div class="container mx-auto px-6 text-center md:pt-20 pb-52">
        <img src="~/assets/images/illustration-intro.png" class="mx-auto" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

is there a way to make the first method working
im using "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.11.4"
and "nuxt": "^3.11.1",
full tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

export default {
  content: [
    `/components/**/*.{vue,js,ts}`,
    `/layouts/**/*.vue`,
    `/pages/**/*.vue`,
    `/composables/**/*.{js,ts}`,
    `/plugins/**/*.{js,ts}`,
    `/utils/**/*.{js,ts}`,
    `/App.{js,ts,vue}`,
    `/app.{js,ts,vue}`,
    `/Error.{js,ts,vue}`,
    `/error.{js,ts,vue}`,
    `/nuxt.config.{js,ts}`,
  ],
  darkMode: 'selector',
  
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        darkBlue: "hsl(217, 28%, 15%)",
        darkBlue1: "hsl(218, 28%, 13%)",
        darkBlue2: "hsl(216, 53%, 9%)",
        darkBlue3: "hsl(219, 30%, 18%)",
        accentCyan: "hsl(176, 68%, 64%)",
        accentBlue: "hsl(198, 60%, 50%)",
        lightRed: "hsl(0, 100%, 63%)",   
    },
      backgroundImage: {
        'logo-dark-mode': "url('~/assets/images/logo-dark-mode.svg')",
        'logo-light-mode': "url('~/assets/images/logo-light-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-dark-mode': "url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-dark-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-light-mode': "url('~/assets/images/bg-curvy-light-mode.svg')",
    },
  },
},
variants: {
  extend: {
    backgroundImage: ['dark'],
  },
},
  plugins: [],
}


full nuxt.config.ts
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  extends: [ 

   ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/google-fonts',
    '@nuxtjs/color-mode',
  ],
  colorMode: {
    preference: 'system', // default value of $colorMode.preference
    fallback: 'light', // fallback value if not system preference found
    hid: 'nuxt-color-mode-script',
    globalName: '__NUXT_COLOR_MODE__',
    componentName: 'ColorScheme',
    classPrefix: '',
    classSuffix: '',
    storageKey: 'nuxt-color-mode'
  },
  tailwindcss: {
    configPath: 'tailwind.config.js',
    cssPath: ["~/assets/css/tailwind.css", { injectPosition: 0 }],
    exposeConfig: false,
    config:{},
    injectPosition: 0,
    viewer: true,
  },
  googleFonts: {
    families: {
      Inter: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
      Raleway: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900],
      Roboto: [100, 300, 400, 500, 700,900],
      "Open Sans": [300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800],
    },
    display: 'swap',
    download: true
  },
  components: [
    { path: '~/components/Icones', prefix: 'Special' },
    '~/components'
]
})


thanks in advance
it is mention in the details section

I would recommend moving your images folder into the public folder. Then you can use the images like this:
backgroundImage: {
        'logo-dark-mode': "url('/images/logo-dark-mode.svg')",
        'logo-light-mode': "url('/images/logo-light-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-dark-mode': "url('/images/bg-curvy-dark-mode.svg')",
        'curvy-light-mode': "url('/images/bg-curvy-light-mode.svg')",
    },

